# WebGL browser compatibility

Tags: testing, browser, webgl

Which browsers are compatible & non compatible with WebGL (desktop+ mobile)? Does someone got any good reference/links summarizing which browsers are not compatible yet with WebGL technology? Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl Pretty good resource for various web apis

Comment: Do you know any code alternative to replace WebGL technology as it seems to have lots of browser restrictions. I heard about 3D unity code ? let me know if you know any alternative technology working with 3D design.Thank you, this is great help.

Comment: Unity 3d can be used to create a game for desktop, mobile and web, but it uses a web player plugin that users have to download. Unity 5 is experimenting with ASM.js as well. Which would of course have the same webgl restrictions.